# Syncing the playing of audio files

Tags: html, html5-audio

I wish to play a list of words. Each word is represented by audio recordings of that word in three different dialects. All three audio files should start playing simultaneously, for each word. The code below works most of the time, but sometimes the three audio files will play out of sync for a given word. Why is this and how can I fix it?

**UPDATE:** 
I think the issue is that the audio has to be fetched and stored on the client's machine in some sort of cache. This is my conclusion at least since I notice that problems are more prevalent when new words are added to the playlist. Can I cache all the audio for all words before I start playing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Player</title>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){

var _dialects = ["c","m","u"];

var _playlist = 
[
    "ta_x", 
    "me_x", 
    "ag",
    "rith",
    "agus",
    "ag",
    "ceol",
];

var _players = new Array(); 
for (var i=0;i<_dialects.length;i++)
{
    _players[i] = document.getElementById("audio_player_"+(i+1));
}

var _number_of_available_players = _dialects.length;
var _playlist_index = 0;

var _play_button = document.getElementById("play_button");

function play()
{
    _playlist_index = 0;
    _play_button.disabled  = true;
    next();
}

function next()
{
    if(_number_of_available_players == _dialects.length)
    {
        if(_playlist_index < _playlist.length)
        {
            for (var i=0;i<_players.length;i++)
            {
                if (_players[i].canPlayType('audio/mpeg;')) 
                {
                    _players[i].src = "http://www.focloir.ie/media/ei/sounds/" + _playlist[_playlist_index] + "_"+_dialects[i]+".mp3";
                }
                else
                {
                    _players[i].src = "http://www.focloir.ie/media/ei/sounds_ogg/" + _playlist[_playlist_index] + "_"+_dialects[i]+".ogg";
                }
                _players[i].play();
            }
            _playlist_index = _playlist_index + 1;
            _number_of_available_players = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            _play_button.disabled  = false;
        }
    }
}

function end()
{
    _number_of_available_players = _number_of_available_players + 1
    next();
}

for (var i=0;i<_players.length;i++)
{
    _players[i].addEventListener('ended', end);
}
_play_button.addEventListener('click', play);

}//]]>  

</script>
</head>

<body>
    <audio id = "audio_player_1"></audio>
    <audio id = "audio_player_2"></audio>
    <audio id = "audio_player_3"></audio>
    <button id = "play_button">Play</button>
</body>
</html>
```